# Windows Server 2012 Standard 64bit Windows Update high RAM usage

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-update

We haven't installed updates on this server for a while, there were a couple I installed last night, and, since, it just scans for updates indefinitely and never actually finishes. I know that there should be like an other 140 or so as we had a similar server inside the same VMWare instance that had also not been updated in a long time.

I tried the usual, sfc scan (which did find stuff that it then fixed), DISM restore health, delete the software distribution folder, but nothing, it just searches for updates indefinitely, and, while it does so, the svchost.exe process hosting it goes up to 2 GB whereas on an other 2012 R2 for example it barely uses 400 MB when searching for updates.

I guess this is part of why it never finishes searching for updates?

I had a look at my security log, it's no bigger than 130 MB on the hard drive.

I know that Windows 7 had an issue with high ram usage when searching for updates and there was an update that fixed that, does anyone know of a similar thing that fixes this on 2012 Standard?

A second sfc scan found nothing and neither did a chkdsk.

I have also run the Windows Update Diagnostic troubleshooter but that hasn't helped either, it just keeps on finding the same errors and at first says it can't fix them, then says it has fixed them, but the service still takes up 2 GBs of RAM and then it still checks for updates for ever and just whirls around without reaching a conclusion as to whether there are any or not.

Thanks.

Comment: It is normal if you don't have the KB2919355 update installed or did not install from an '2012 R2 Update 1' media source. Sounds like the server just does not have enough memory.

Comment: Server has 16 GB of RAM, only uses 8  at the moment with WU taking 2. I'll install the KB and see how it goes.

Comment: Hi @GregAskew, I just wanted to say that I am unable to install KB2919355 as installing any updates, even manually downloaded ones, requires them to check for windows updates which in turn takes forever. I was attempting to install KB2919442 as apparently it is the first pre-requisite according to https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42334 but it's just stuck at "searching for updates on this computer..."
No idea what media source was used to install this OS... 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, I only now realized this is in fact just 2012 Standard and not 2012 R2, so sorry everyone!

Comment: After you nuke SoftwareDistribution, you should reboot and run the [Windows Update Diagnostic tool](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9830262).

Comment: Hello @MichaelHampton, I forgot to say that I did already try the diagnostic tool as well and still nothing. Weirdly though, it finds the same issues every time I run it which are "Windows Update error 0x80070005(2019-01-18-T-01_51_54P) Fixed" and "Problems installing recent updates Not Fixed"

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, after running the troubleshooter again like I did before, now it says that it has indeed fixed the aforementioned error, but it still makes no difference. This time it also says that "Service registration is missing or corrupt - Fixed" but it still doesn't make a difference...

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, not even WSUS Offline worked in the end as it apparently needs to use the Windows Update process to list missing IDs...

Comment: Hi @GregAskew, any further thoughts perhaps since I have really tried everything? Thanks!

Comment: @user757392 - Check your WindowsUpdateLog, and if possible, upload it on dropbox, etc. and share the same. Will try to see if there is somthing in the logs.

Comment: Hello @Am_I_Helpful, thank you for that. I'll give that a go and let you know.
I just wanted to say that I also tried KB2937636 and the latest January 2019 security rollup and it still makes no difference... KB2937636 says that it's not applicable even despite me not having that update installed...

Comment: Hello @Am_I_Helpful, I can see a lot of "2019-01-24 22:12:06:245  920 142c Agent WARNING: Failed to evaluate Installable rule, updateId = {3647D951-3672-4977-B79B-E570B4A3F719}.209, hr = 8007045B" errors, perhaps this is the main thing? The log is huge, annoying I can't just upload it here... (Just to clarify, this server does NOT use WSUS)

Comment: @user757392 - Won't be able to comment much unless I see the `WindowsUpdate.log file`! It's hardly close to 5 MB, and you can upload it on cloud, if possible. Lastly, how is this server expected to download updates - from Internet? In that case, whether the Microsoft Windows Update URL is accessible on the server?

Comment: hi @Am_I_Helpful, yes, from the internet, the URL is accessible. Sorry, I just don't have any cloud services I can use as we're not allowed to use the company drive for public links. I can't believe that serverfault doesn't have an upload feature...

Comment: @user757392 - Unfortunately, in such scenario I won't be able to help! I'd suggest you to try the script mentioned here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-Windows-Update-Agent-d824badc. This will definitely help you for the clients having problems while downloading the updates!